# How to delete similar phrases in multiple files in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have these codes:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverQr, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

These codes are repeated in multiple files in my android project.

Is there a way to delete all these phrases in multiple files (let's say in 100s files) easily?

Comment: You mean you want a way to avoid repetition or you actually want a way to delete text from a bunch of files?

Comment: i want a way to delete those similar texts from a bunch of files

Comment: @EhsanRosdi Did you tried with `cmd + shift + r` or `Edit > Find > Replace in Path...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Edit > Find > Replace in Path...`

You can further limit the scope of the search to the project, a module, a directory only or even a custom scope.

Comment: Ok, yours better.

Comment: Nice, unaware such thing exists. :D